# How to Create Subdirectories for S3 Bucket with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

if I wanted to create a bucket with a layout like this:

bucket/

```
├─ subdir-1/
│  ├─ subsubdir-1/
├─ subdir-2/
├─ subdir-3/
```

how could I do this using the cdk?

I know that you can just upload a file with the requisite because subdirectories don't really do anything bc S3 is a file system, but I have a use case because Spark is expecting a subdirectory to exist for some reason.

And if you have to create a file in the directory, that is a really poor solution because you lose the ability to configure your S3 bucket within the CDK (things like versioning, vpc access, replication controls, etc.)

Comment: If you really, really need a directory you need to upload a file / object with 0 bytes and have its key end with a /

Comment: @luk2302 how to I do that with the CDK?

Comment: Use BucketDeployment with a source being an empty string. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.Source.html#static-dataobjectkey-data

Answer (score 0):

Since folders don't really exist in S3, and files only have a 'prefix' - which by convention results in an apparent directory structure... take a look at the BucketDeployment construct and upload 0 byte placeholder files named `subdir-1/subsubdir-1/placeholder` that Spark will ignore.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that folders aren't a thing in S3 and it's just an illusion created by the web interface.